# "principal end of an association" - EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'XYZ.Models.Attachment' and 'XYZ.Models.Accounts.User'. The
>   principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using
>   either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

That error I get, when I try to `update-database` with my EF Models.

Part of User.cs:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int MainPhotoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MainPhotoId")]
    public virtual Attachment Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Attachment.cs

```
[Table("Attachments")]
public class Attachment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AttachmentId { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }


    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

    public bool del { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }

}
```

Why I get this error? And how to resolve it?

Regards

Comment: Are the classes complete or did you leave out some properties? The exception doesn't make sense with this model. By convention there is clearly a one-to-many relationship between the two and `User` is clearly the "principal end".

Comment: OUH! Sorry! I forgot to paste main part of `User.cs` model.. Look at edit now please.

Comment: Besides the MainPhoto can a User have many other attachments?

Comment: Yes! Of course. I just want to use `lazy loading` on `MainPhoto`. But general, user can have also other attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping conventions detect a one-to-one relationship between `User.Photo` and `Attachment.Author` and cannot infer what the principal and what the dependent end is. Hence the exception.

Actually, according to your comments, you want *two* relationships and not a single one-to-one relationship. You can achieve that only by overriding the convention with Fluent API and you probably need to make one of the relationships *optional* because otherwise you have a circular mutual dependency between `User` and `Attachment`. You can, for example, make the `User.Photo` property optional by choosing a nullable foreign key:

```
public int? MainPhotoId { get; set; }
```

Then the mapping would look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Photo)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.MainPhotoId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Author)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId);
```

With this mapping you can remove the `[ForeignKey]` attributes because the definition of the FK properties is part of the Fluent API mapping (`HasForeignKey`).